# Excel - Conditional Date Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using Excel, I would like to create a conditional Date formula as follows:

If the Date is Greater than or Equal to January 18, 2013, Enter $220.00 in this cell.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If cell A1 holds the date try this formula in another cell

`=IF(A1>=DATE(2013,1,18),220,"")`

format the formula cell as currency

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 =IF(A1>DATEVALUE("17/1/2012"),220)
```